# spark: scramble RDDs and zip them

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two RDDs of the same length, and I would like to zip them together randomly (e.g. first RDD is (A,B,C,D) and second is (W,X,Y,Z) and I want a random zip like (AX,BZ,CW,DY). What's a fast way to do this using pySpark?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
x = sc.parallelize(['A','B','C','D'])
y = sc.parallelize(['W','X','Y','Z'])
x = x.takeSample(False, 4)
y = y.takeSample(False, 4)
combine = zip(x,y)
combine
>> [('D', 'Z'), ('B', 'X'), ('A', 'W'), ('C', 'Y')]
```

Comment: I don't want to `take`, I want a new RDD with the zipped old RDDs in random order. And it looks like `sample` with fraction `1.0` doesn't re-order things.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand

s = lambda x: (x[1], x[0])

def shuffle(rdd):
    return rdd.map(lambda x: (x, )) \
              .toDF(["data"]).withColumn("rand", rand()) \
              .orderBy("rand") \
              .rdd.map(lambda x: x.data)

shuffle(rdd1).zipWithIndex().map(s).join(rdd2.zipWithIndex().map(s)).values()
```